# kotlin coroutines precedence of execution

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need help understanding the outcome of the following 2 pieces of code

**1st snippet**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch {
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            println("Task from nested launch")
        }

        println("Task from coroutine scope")
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over")
}
```

**And, the 2nd snippet**

```
fun main() = runBlocking { 
    launch {
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }

    println("Coroutine scope is over") 
}
```

**The outcome of the 1st snippet is:**

```
Task from coroutine scope
Task from runBlocking
Task from nested launch
Coroutine scope is over
```

**The outcome of the 2nd snippet is:**

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from runBlocking
```

So, the question is why were the statements printed in that order?

Comment: They don't have to, the only thing is that once a coruotine scope closes all of its coroutines will have terminated. Hence in your first example "Coroutine scope is over" comes after the statements inside `coroutineScope`.

Comment: In the second example, the statement `Coroutine scope is over` is a lie. You print it from within the coroutine scope.

Comment: hey @MarkoTopolnik, may you elaborate more? what do you mean with that?

Comment: `runBlocking` establishes the coroutine scope you refer to, right? It's not over when you print `Coroutine scope is over`.

Comment: @afairplayer did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `1st snippet` you are using `coroutineScope` which, as you can see from the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) is defined as a `suspend` function, so it's blocking the current thread and `"Coroutine scope is over"` is not printed until `coroutineScope` block has completed.

For the `2nd snippet` the string `"Coroutine scope is over"` is printed before `"Task from run blocking"` because its println it's executed in the main thread, and `launch` which runs in a worker thread has not finished yet its job.

```
fun mainOne() = runBlocking {
  launch {
      println("Task from runBlocking")
  }

  // coroutineScope is defined as a suspend function, so it's blocking the current thread
  coroutineScope {

      launch {
          // worker thread, slower than main thread, printed after "Task from coroutine scope"
          println("Task from nested launch")
      }
      // main thread, printed before "Task from nested launch" within CoroutineScope
      println("Task from coroutine scope")
  }

  // main thread is now free to run and it prints the string below
  println("Coroutine scope is over")
}


fun mainTwo() = runBlocking {
    launch {
        // worker thread, slower than main thread, printed after "Coroutine scope is over" due to concurrency
        println("Task from runBlocking")
    }
    // main thread is running and prints the string below before launch job has finished.
    // If you put a delay here you'll notice that launch job gets completed before "Coroutine scope is over"
    // E.g delay(2000)
    println("Coroutine scope is over")
}
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Without overriding the dispatcher all these tasks run on the main thread

Answer (score 1):

Calling `launch` just puts a task on the queue while calling `coroutineScope` suspends the current coroutine until the new coroutineScope completes.

This is what happens in Snippet 2:

- puts "Task from runBlocking" on queue
- prints "Coroutine scope is over"
- executes sole task from queue (prints "Task from runBlocking")

This is what happens in Snippet 1

- puts "Task from runBlocking" on queue
- coroutineScope (a suspend function) is called! The suspend function is called immediately and the mainCoroutine will not proceed until the suspend function completes
- puts "Task from nested launch" on queue
- prints "Task from coroutine scope"
- suspends execution since coroutineScope can't complete until it's child in the queue completes
- first task in queue is executed "Task from runBlocking"
- second task in queue is executed "Task from nested launch"
- new CoroutineScope completes since its child task just completed! Back to main coroutine!
- prints "Coroutine scope is over"